# Where is my com.something.myapp stored at when I run my project in eclipse and load it to my phone?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, filewriter

When I run my android project in eclipse through my device the app shows up on my phone with the little android dude.  It runs fine, does what it is supposed to do.  I am writing to some '.txt' files in my app and I cant locate the .txt files in my storage system.  Also for that matter when I navigate to "/data/where the apps for all my other applications are stored" it does not appear there I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions(also I cant find it anywhere the "com.example.app" in my file system).

Note: when I manually transfer the .apk to the storage system on my device and install/run it the file appears. I would like to avoid having to manually transfer my .apk everytime I test it.  Also I am using the phongap file writing api although I dont think that should matter.

Answer (score 0):

Are just looking for it with some file explorer or with adb? If not try using it. You can find it under adt-bundle-*\sdk\platform-tools\

with your favourite shell run `adb shell`

then you can copy data from your app with the pull command

```
adb pull /data/app/com.example.app/your_text_file.txt <local filesystem>
```

For more check out the adb tutorial.